# returning something other than the actual label in a list view

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

If I have a listview which is populated with a string array say:

```
Mazda
Renault
Holden
Audi
```

and when I want to click on an item, rather than returning string "Mazda" I'd rather return an associated number e.g. Mazda Returns 0, Renault returns 1 etc.

Is this possible and would I see a significant performance increase on querying an 
SQLite DB using just ints rather than strings?

Thanks, 
M

Comment: you can get position by useing array.index method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your listview there are adapter are use, so in this method there are position variable also already exist there.if you print it in `logcat` it will get every time position of your list-item.you need to handle it in array easily

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String pen = o.toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the pen: " + " " + pen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String[] MY_CARS = new STRING[] { Mazda, Renault, Holden, Audi };

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, MY_CARS));

  ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyListView);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item at Position "+pos+" was clicked. This corresponds to "+MY_CARS[pos],
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
  });
}
```

This should return the position of the item in the list that was clicked, which should be the index of the array.

I am not sure whether you will get a significant increase in db performance though.